# help! no sound from guitar to amp

Tags: electric-guitar

[image: hopefully this picture is helpful]
i’ve had this problem for a while but it would fix itself, but now when i plug in my epiphone les paul special ii into my amp i get no sound. I checked all the basics and yes the amp is plugged in and on, the guitar volume is up, and the cable works with my acoustic-electric. I’m not an expert with guitars so i don’t know what i need to look for so i included the picture. I also unscrewed the input jack and the wire seemed to be attached. This is an inexpensive guitar so I don’t really want to pay to have it fixed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just looking at it won’t do much to troubleshoot it. You need a volt ohm meter or continuity tester and then you can use that to test each part of the circuit to find the problem. If you don’t already have one of those then paying to get it fixed is probably cheaper than buying one.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - a cheap multimeter isn't going to break the bank. It'll do most checks like this one. More to the point, it's there for the next problem - be it a duff guitar lead or a fuse in the mains plug. Paying to fix the guitar is fine, but next time is more money out.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. When i just had it plugged in, i was getting buzzing feedback after i strummed, but when i touched the strings the buzzing stopped. Also when i turned up the volume louder than usual, i could play and it worked like normal, but the buzzing when i took my fingers off the strings is still there and its annoying. is there an easy fix to this? Like i said the problem has gone away before so i’m assuming there is.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a soldering iron, re-make all the soldered joints.  Hook up a temporary direct connection from a pickup to the output jack - or perhaps to a replacement output jack (no nead to mount it yet). Short out the volume and tone controls.  You should see where the problem is.

If all this is over your head and you CAN'T use a soldering iron, you're not going to be able to fix it anyway.

I'd normally now advise about not knowing what you're doing... expensive repair... etc.    But there's only a few components in there, all cheaply replacable. You can't do much harm.  (Go on, prove me wrong :-)  )

Comment: And he's already taken the crucial picture so it all goes back the same way!

Comment: Quite likely a dirty pot.